# Importing Text Files to be read using Scanner

Tags: java, text, import, fileinputstream

```
 private void readWords() throws IOException {
    initialCt = readFrom("C:\\Curses1.txt", initialWords);
    midCt     = readFrom("C:\\Curses2.txt", middleWords);
    endCt     = readFrom("C:\\Curses3.txt", endingWords);
  } // readWords()

  // Pre: fileName is the name of an input file. Tokens (items) in the
  // file are strings separated by whitespace.
  // Pre: wordList has been allocated and is large enough to hold all
  // the tokens in the input file.
  // Post: wordList contains all the tokens in the input file, one token
  // per string.


  private int readFrom(String fileName, String[] wordList) throws IOException {

     int count= 0;  

     FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(fileName);
     Scanner scan2 = new Scanner (fstream);

     while (scan2.hasNext()){

         initialWords[count] =scan2.nextLine();
         middleWords[count] = scan2.nextLine();
         endingWords [count] = scan2.nextLine();

         String words = scan2.next();
         ++count;
      }

     return count;
  } // readFrom()

    Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
    at Curses.readFrom(Curses.java:95)
    at Curses.readWords(Curses.java:63)
    at Curses.run(Curses.java:51)
    at Curses.main(Curses.java:131)
```

I am trying to read in three different text files and store their values in three different arrays but java cannot find the file. This is only part of the class but this is where the error is occurring.   Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is the error or unexpected result?  In general, posting a compiler or runtime error, error/debug log, or something of the sort helps people help you better, faster.

Comment: I am trying to figure out what the error is. It has something to do with reading the files I believe

Answer (score 0):

i believe it is happening because of the `String words = scan2.next();`
if the file doesn't have the 4th line then this exception would be thrown. that is the only possible way i can think of. check the files if there is a 4th line.

Comment: there are strings on about 20 lines

Comment: can you post the exact contents of the text file..?